# Error Upgrade Jquery.min into Jquery.1.9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, syntax-error, upgrade

I try this code in jqueri.min1.2.js  Work but in Jquery.1.9.js not Work

```
    $('a.comment').livequery("click", function(e){

        var getpID =  $(this).parent().attr('id').replace('commentBox-','');    
        var comment_text = $("#commentMark-"+getpID).val();

        if(comment_text != "Write a comment...")
        {
            $.post("add_comment.php?comment_text="+comment_text+"&post_id="+getpID, {

            }, function(data){

                $('#CommentPosted'+getpID).append($(data).fadeIn('slow'));
                $("#commentMark-"+getpID).val("Write a comment...");                    
            });
        }

    });
```

Ouput on console "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:"
ON MY BROWSER NO RETURN FROM add_comment.php

Help me please...
How to output is Html response from add_comment.php ...
HOW TO OUTPUT html   FROM add_comment.php

Comment: which line has the error ? Did you use migrate plugin ?

Comment: which is the line throwing the error

Comment: also is there any other error in the console and what is the value of variable `getpID`

Comment: function(data){

                $('#CommentPosted'+getpID).append($(data).fadeIn('slow'));
                $("#commentMark-"+getpID).val("Write a comment...");

No output on my html pages.. 
 
This true output  FROM  $.post("add_comment.php

Comment: NO any Error... value of getpID = idpost of comment

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your actual problem but I think that, will upgrading the jquery lib, after loading the updated jquery lib you need to add jquery migrate js, which will make the older lib functions work in newer one.